# onPull React Native ScrollView

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-props

- What is the pull `Props` in `ScrollView` ?

Or in other words

- Which `Prop` should run when we get to the first item in `ScrollView` ?

For example

```
 <ScrollView
      scrollEnabled={this.state.scrollEnabled}
      onScroll={(y) => {
          if (y.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y <= 0 ) {
               // 
           }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you describe it in greater detail?

Comment: I completed the question.

Comment: I still don't understand. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When my list came to the first item and it showed the white semicircle on Android

Comment: Are you looking for specifying a function that is called when user does the pull down gesture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think you're looking for the refreshControl prop.

See the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#refreshcontrol